# JavaScript scroll element to middle not working

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll

I'm passing html elements to an ES6 file and I want to scroll that element in the middle of the page. But `window.scrollTo()` is not working

ES6 Code:

```
export const isScrolledIntoView = (element) => {   
    const elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    const absoluteElementTop = elementRect.top + window.pageYOffset;
    const middle = absoluteElementTop - (window.innerHeight / 2);
    window.scrollTo(0, middle);        
};
```

Any suggestion what's wrong?

Comment: "not working" is kind of vague...

Comment: Well I'm not getting the desired output and I tried to debug it using 'debugger' but window.scrollTo() is not working in my code.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the [window.scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll) method is available and works?

Comment: So, if you want help in debugging, we really want you to give us code that will reproduce the issue. In this case, adding a Stack Snippet with the HTML and the function showing how it's not working would go a long way toward making this a good question.

Comment: How is isScrolledIntoView called? Did you add console.log lines to see what the values are?